# Do the eigenvalues of a matrix need to be in the same field as the elements of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Do the eigenvalues of a matrix need to be in the same field as the elements of the matrix? I believe they do not since, for instance, I was taught that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues and this would mean that this is not always the case. What puzzles me is that I have seen people claiming that some real matrix has no eigenvalues simply because the eigenvalues were all complex numbers. Were they right?

Comment: Yes, they were right in the sense that a matrix with real entries can have real eigenvalues and/or pairs of complex conjugate eigenvalues (so for instance if $i$ is an eigenvalue, also $-i$ has to be one).

Comment: If the matrix has entries from a field that is not algebraically closed, then not necessarily.  This is because the eigenvalues of a matrix are roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends upon the context. If, say, you have a $n\times n$ *real* matrix and and someone asks you what are its eigenvalues, then it is implicit that you should provide the *real* eigenvalues. And perhaps that there is none. On the other hand, it may be implicit that, in fact, you are after the *complex* eigenvalues.

On the other hand, if the matrix is real, then the trace is real, but it may well have non-real eigenvalues. For instance, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ has null trace, but its eigenvalues are $\pm i$.

Comment: So basically any real $n \times n$ matrix has $n$ eigenvalues (with different multiplicities of course), but not all of them are real numbers? However, all the other properties of eigenvalues are preserved as your example shows, right?

Comment: Yes, except that I would say that it has $n$ eigenvalues if you count them with their multiplicities.

Answer (score 1):

A real matrix can have no eigenvalues in **exactly** the same way that the real polynomial equation $x^2+1=0$ can have no solutions.

Whether it is true or not depends entirely on who is taking, who they're talking to, and what they are talking about.